# Append to a non primary key column, and insert if it doesn't exist at all

Tags: mysql

I have a table of structure:

```
+----+-----+-------+
| Id | Key | Value |
+----+-----+-------+
|  1 | A   | BCD   |
|  2 | B   | XYZ   |
+----+-----+-------+
```

Here, id is the primary key. I want to write a query that appends a string to `value` agains a `key` if it exists, or else, should insert a new row.
For example, if I need to append `PQR` to a value where `key` is `A`, it should update `BCD` to `BCDPQR`. But if `key` is `X`, which doesn't exist, it should insert a new row with `key` as `X` and `Value` as `PQR`.
I am looking to do it in one single query, and not multiple, also not a procedure.
Database: MySQL.

Comment: Insert...on duplicate key https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: I guess this works if my key column had been a primary key. All I have is key against which I need to make the update. I dont have the id.

Comment: Are you saying KEY is a column but the contents are not unique and there is no unique index on KEY?

Comment: Yes. Key should ideally be unique, but there's no unique key constraint on it. And not possible for me to change it on production now.

Comment: Replace https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html and INSERt INTO ON Duplicate should work, test it simply

Comment: Both insert,,on duplicate key and replace require a unique index - since you cannot supply one then you cannot do this in one single query.

Comment: Instead of a simgle query use a stored procedure, which checks if there is an entry and then inserts or update, but on highfrequented servern this sometimes fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in one SQL statement, because commented above, INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE only works if your `KEY` column is part of a unique key. So you're going to have to write some code.

First start a transaction, because you'll want to lock the row until you commit:

```
START TRANSACTION;
```

Do a locking read for the row:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE `KEY` = 'A' FOR UPDATE;
```

This will either return a row, or else no rows. You will write code to check the result for this difference.

If the SELECT did return a row, then UPDATE the row with the ID you just fetched:

```
UPDATE MyTABLE SET VALUE = CONCAT(VALUE, 'PQR') WHERE ID = ?
```

If no row were fetched by the SELECT, then INSERT a new row:

```
INSERT INTO MyTABLE SET `KEY` = 'A', VALUE = 'PQR';
```

Don't forget to COMMIT, which will release the lock on the row so another client can do their work.

```
COMMIT;
```

The code and logic to do this task is not difficult, and should be well within the skills of any software developer.

Comment: Yes, this works and I also have a few other ways of doing this. But was wondering if there's any way of handling it in one query.

Comment: No, there is not.